# Обработка строк dataframe pandas с логическим условием

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть dataframe о действиях пользователя вида: user_id, acttime (unixtime)
где user_id может повторяться, если было более 1 события (игровая сессия) в acttime

Мне нужно на основе этих данных вычислить время старта игровой сессии, время окончания игровой сессии, длину игровой сессии.

Спасибо!

Comment: [Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то решение мне видится через сводную таблицу.

Перед решением импортируем numpy:

```
import numpy as np
```

Допустим у нас есть DataFrame:

[image: Начальный датафрейм]

И нам нужно получить начало игровой сессии, конец игровой сессии, и общее время.

Если я правильно понял: начало игровой сессии = минимальное unix-время у юзера, тогда конец игровой сессии = максимальное unix-время у юзера.

Получается мы можем решить эту задачу с помощью сводной таблицы.

```
df.pivot_table(index='user_id',values='unixtime',aggfunc=['min','max',np.ma.ptp])
```

Функция `np.ma.ptp` возвращает разницу максимального значения и минимального

И как итог мы получаем необходимый DataFrame:

[image: Конечный датафрейм]